# Feedparser stopped working

Tags: python, feedparser

Yesterday I installed feedparser (on OSX 10.5) and it worked fine, but now it stopped working.

This is the script (copied from feedparser documentation)

```
import feedparser
d = feedparser.parse('http://feedparser.org/docs/examples/atom10.xml')
d['feed']['title']
u'Sample Feed'
```

It tells me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 3, in <module>
    import feedparser
  File "example.py", line 2, in <module>
    d = feedparser.parse('http://feedparser.org/docs/examples/atom10.xml')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'parse'
```

But also an actual script using feedparser stopped working, same error.

Comment: Did you named a module of your own feedparser?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean?

Comment: oh wait, I get what you mean. Stupid, I named my test-script feedparser.py. Thanks :)

Comment: wow, old question. but I just did the same thing. I separated some code to test and named it after the module I was testing! I feel like an idiot, but this just killed way too much time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The point is when there is a script named feedparser.py, python will considered it as a module to import with higher priority than the module installed.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with Name of file. Python confuses between name of file and module name.